# How to deal with async code returning before I want it to?

Tags: node.js, design-patterns, promise, sequelize.js

I have a function, which contains code along the lines of...

```
db.query(query).then(results => {
    _.each(results, result => {
        db.query(anotherQuery).then(
            /* modify result based off anotherQuery results */
        });
    });
    resolve(results);
});
```

What is happening, of course, is that `resolve(results))` is being hit whilst the second request to the DB is being run, which means that the promise is not resolved to add the additional data before being returned.

Is there a pattern I can use to avoid this? I am using Sequelize, which is backed by Bluebird for Promises. It's a pattern I've come across a few times, and I've already looked at using [wait.for](https://github.com/rochejul/sequelize-mocking) but it seems to be outdated and unsupporting of Promises.

Comment: What is `resolve`? You should `return` a promise from a `then` callback to chain it.

Comment: @Bergi resolve is the resolve parameter of new Promise((resolve, reject) => ...

Comment: I feared so. Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Promise.all`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.all.html) function provided by Bluebird itself:

```
return db.query(query).then(results => {
    const promises = results.map(result => {
        return db.query(anotherQuery).then(
            /* modify result based off anotherQuery results */
        });
    });

    return Promise.all(promises);
});
```